# Please help me pdo MySQL select

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find what I am doing wrong - I cannot understand or find some information about it.

In short, there are 3 rows in the table.

```
  id login mail        ip 
   1 me    me@mail.ru  127.0.0.1
   2 me2   me2@mail.ru 4234234
   3 me3   me3@mail.ru 4234234
```

When I execute a verification request does this data already exist, but it processes it from the end
 (how to do the opposite?)

For example, "post" request: login(me3), mail(me2@mail.ru), ip(127.0.0.1)
Then he will show me - from the end, that is, ip! I changed the IP, and he showed me by mail, but not from the login

How can I fix this - or am I doing something wrong (login in the 3rd line - mail in the second line, and IP - in the first) How to do it so that everything does not start with IP (that is, not from the end)

```
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT login, email, ip FROM users WHERE login=:login OR email=:email OR ip=:ip");
        $stmt->execute(['login' => $login, 'email' => $email, 'ip' => $ip]);
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($row['login']==$login) {
            echo "Sorry, username is already taken!";
        }
        elseif ($row['email']==$email) {
            echo "Sorry, the email id is already taken!";
        }
        elseif ($row['ip']==$ip) {
            echo "You have already registered - only one registration is allowed.";
        }
        else {
            echo "All is well!";
        }
        var_dump ($row);
    array(3) { ["login"]=> string(5) "me" ["email"]=> string(12) "me@mail.ru" 
    ["ip"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" }
```

Of course, I have an alternative - but I would like to do it in one simple way!

```
        $sqlCheckLogin = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_login FROM ".DB_PREFIX."users WHERE user_login=:login");
        $sqlCheckLogin->execute(['login' => $login]);
        if ($sqlCheckLogin->fetchColumn()) {
            $message = 'User with this login is already registered! Enter another login.';
        }
        else 
        {
            $sqlCheckEmail = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_email FROM ".DB_PREFIX."users WHERE user_email=:email");
            $sqlCheckEmail->execute(['email' => $email]);
            if ($sqlCheckEmail->fetchColumn()) {
                $message = 'User with this e-mail is already registered!';
            }
            else 
            {
                $sqlCheckIp = $pdo->prepare("SELECT user_ip FROM ".DB_PREFIX."users WHERE user_ip=:ip");
                $sqlCheckIp->execute(['ip' => $ip]);
                if ($sqlCheckIp->fetchColumn()) {
                    $message = 'You have already registered on the site, re-registration is prohibited and punishable by the rules of the site!';
                }
```

I was looking for examples - and I did not find the information, so I think someone here can tell me what direction to go. How to turn these 3 requests into 1?

---

### Result, Thanks to all!

The best option is to check the login separately and check the email separately, now I understand my stupidity and the fact that I could not find something like that for so long.

Of course, I can check everything at once and display information that something already exists, but it is impossible to determine in which order. And with a separate test for existence, we know exactly what we have and know exactly what information to display.

Comment: How do you know that a single IP is one person? What if they're using a VPN, lives in a dorm with others, shares network with someone...? What if my IP is dynamic, and I get a new IP, where someone already registered?

Comment: You are trying to do this to simply, but it is not a simple process.

Comment: You should go in the direction into using a persistent cookie, Etags stuff like that but those also will not work if somebody is using more browsers.. keep in mind in some countries they have laws against using persistent tracking methodes EU's General Data Protection Regulation  (GDPR) comes to mind..

Comment: In general, I think that either I said wrong - or it is really difficult to do! The top code works fine, but vice versa!

Comment: yes like @RiggsFolly 's says this is not that simple, HTTP protocol is stateless that means you can't uniquelly identity a person based on a HTTP request, you might be able to get the users MAC adress with a signed java applet or with [signed javascript](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html) code for firefox

Comment: @Raymond Nijland I do not understand where
 cookie or http -  I just want to check if there is data in the database or not - but in one query!

Comment: @АндрейКаргин so what is wrong with your query `WHERE login=:login OR email=:email OR ip=:ip` ? IMHO that is checking what you need.

Comment: "I do not understand where cookie or http" well i explained you that it is in thoery not possible to uniquelly identity a person in a PHP/SQL code which you seams to be doing here.. `$message = 'You have already registered on the site, re-registration is prohibited and punishable by the rules of the site!';` right?.. You would need a MAC adress which is not send over the internet but you can get with most likely with a signed java applet or signed javscript code and use a MAC adress to uniquelly identity a LAN card, unless they change the MAC adress offcource which is possible in some OS..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Or my network card goes Poof and I buy a new one

Comment: @Raymond Nijland IP has nothing to do with it! I just want to execute one SELECT query: login, email, ip FROM users WHERE login =: login OR email =: email OR ip =: ip - and show that login or email is already in use!

Comment: "IP has nothing to do with it!" if thats the case why is where a `OR ip =: ip` part in the SQL?

Comment: @АндрейКаргин what is wrong with your current implementation???

Comment: @Alex i think this "When I execute a verification request does this data already exist, but it processes it from the **end (how to do the opposite?)**"  meaning the most simply is adding a `ORDER BY` somehow.. But not sure because i don't see or understand his user case and expected results.

Comment: Because you are using 3 OR's in that query you always run the risk of getting more than one result

Comment: @RaymondNijland **but it processes it from the end (how to do the opposite?)** I just completely misunderstand this phrase. I can't translate it into any sense. That is why I've flagged "not clear what you are asking"

Comment: "but it processes it from the end (how to do the opposite?) I just completely misunderstand this phrase. I can't translate it into any sense" well @Alex the question completly was hard to translate to anny sense that the topicstarter was looking for uniqueness on those columns which he commented on your answer, that idea never crossed mine mind when reading this question..

Comment: Is it that you are running a query that will return TWO, or maybe more rows but you are only running ONE Fetch and you want to knod why the ONE ROW you FETCH is not what you expect?

Comment: @ Raymond Nijland Thanks, this ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 1 worked! My fault is that I suppressed the error output and instead of user_id I just wrote id - I even changed places in select but it didn’t work!

Comment: Let's say you fix your code, and everything works as you expect. What happens when someone inserts an ip *while* the code is checking to see if that ip already exists?

Comment: IP is not who does not insert - this is the registration form, ip I get through the function function get_ip()   filter_var($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV4);  or FILTER_VALIDATE_IP, FILTER_FLAG_IPV6  this is not a complete code @Strawberry

Comment: In general, it is really difficult to do - I did a few tests. ORDER BY `id` DESC didn't help either!

Comment: The best option is to check the login separately and check the email separately, now I understand my stupidity and the fact that I could not find something like that for so long.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but just a big comment.

I still can't get what is your goal. But I feel you want to check for unique : login, email and ip.

You can do very straight forward implementation for that.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/JB1EDnr8GBYsTU1z8dRDS/0

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE unique_login(login);
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE unique_ip(ip);
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE unique_email(email);
```

As you can see in the fiddle, MySql will return you the proper error message, which you can use for output.

Another attempt to guess what exactly you are looking for, probably you don't nee `elseif` but just series of `if`s in any order you prefer:

```
  if (empty($row)) {
        echo "All is well!";
  } else {
      if ($row['ip']==$ip) {
        $message .= "You have already registered - only one registration is allowed. \n";
      };
      if ($row['login']==$login) {
        $message .= "Sorry, username is already taken! \n";
      };
      if ($row['email']==$email) {
        $message .= "Sorry, the email id is already taken! \n";
      };

      echo $message;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I just want to check for uniqueness and display an error that something already exists.

Comment: Except that some ISP's use DHCP to allocate IP's so if OP uses `login=:login OR email=:email OR ip=:ip` and I legitimately login using an ip that has been used by someone else legitimately loging in but I now have been allocated the ip address that the other person had previously there will always be more than one result in the resultset

Comment: Or using this the OP will get a false positive, or is that a false negative, anyway the result will be false/wrong

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think OP just ignores real world at the moment. He is not asking for real solution, he wants to achieve some goal. And probably he will be back one day when few people from the same office/city/location(IP) will fail to register, if OP will ever realize that.